# Convert long flat tables (where each column includes both year and category) to one which compares categories and years

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, grouping

I have been trying with no avail to create a program which converts CSVs with 20+ categories where the years and categories are both in the columns, to one where they are split into rows and columns

**How can i do this without having to do it manually for each CSV?**

I never studied IT so my knowledge is quite patchy and all my attempts have currently ended in large inefficient codes.

btw. Im doing this for my bachelor thesis and not for investing or something of that sort

## Example of the data currently looks

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Total Revenue 2006' : ['786'],
   'Total Revenue 2007' : ['643'],
   'Total Revenue 2008' : ['1200'],
   'Total Revenue 2009' : ['1456'],
   'Total Revenue 2010' : ['1675'],
   'Total Employees 2006' : ['42'],
   'Total Employees 2007' : ['55'],
   'Total Employees 2008' : ['65'],
   'Total Employees 2009' : ['45'],
   'Total Employees 2010' : ['60'],
```

## I want to split the categories and years so that the columns are just years and the rows just categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```py
df = df.transpose()
df["temp"] = df.index
df["name"] = df["temp"].map(lambda x: x.rsplit(" ", 1)[0])
df["year"] = df["temp"].map(lambda x: x.rsplit(" ", 1)[1])
df.drop(columns="temp", inplace=True)
result = df.pivot(index='name', columns='year', values=0)
```

refers to
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html
for more

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one as well although a little bit long:

```
transposed_df = df.transpose()
transposed_df.index.name = "Type"
transposed_df.columns = ["Value"]
transposed_df = transposed_df.reset_index()
transposed_df["Year"] = transposed_df.Type.apply(lambda x: x.rsplit(" ", 1)[-1])
transposed_df["Metric"] = transposed_df.Type.apply(lambda x: x.rsplit(" ", 1)[-0])
revenue_df = transposed_df[transposed_df.Metric=="Total Revenue"].set_index("Year")
employee_df = transposed_df[transposed_df.Metric=="Total Employees"].set_index("Year")
revenue_df.drop(["Type", "Metric"], inplace=True, axis=1)
revenue_df.columns = ["Revenue"]
employee_df.drop(["Type", "Metric"], inplace=True, axis=1)
employee_df.columns = ["TotalEmployees"]
combined_df = pd.concat([employee_df, revenue_df], axis=1)
combined_df.head()

    TotalEmployees  Revenue
Year        
2006    42  786
2007    55  643
2008    65  1200
2009    45  1456
2010    60  1675
```